# Undefined method - NOMethod error with Resque gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, builder, resque

I am trying to generate xml file as a background task using resque gem here is the class which generates xml file ....

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] = ARGV.first || ENV['RAILS_ENV']
require File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/../../config/environment")
require  'rubygems'
require 'builder'

class GenerateXml
  @queue = :worker

  def self.perform
    file_name = "#{Time.now.strftime('%Y_%m_%d')}_export.xml"

    xml = Builder::XmlMarkup.new(:target => file_name, :indent => 2)
    xml.instruct!(:xml, :encoding => "UTF-8")

    xml.Postings do
      Result.find_in_batches do |result|
        xml.Posting do
          xml.JobID result.job_id
          xml.JobURL result.job_url
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

and my result model from where I am extracting the fields for the xml tags is like this

```
require 'active_record'

class Result < ActiveRecord::Base
  def job_id
    self.link
  end

  def job_url
    self.link
  end
end
```

My question is why result.job_url and result.job_id from class `GenerateXml` is not able to map to `Result` class correctly?

and one more thing the `Result` class is under app/models directory where as `GenerateXml` class is under lib/jobs directory

Here is the trace of error.

```
      undefined method `job_id' for #<Array:0xb3f26738>

/home/netserv/RubymineProjects/crawler/lib/jobs/generate_xml.rb:22:in `perform'
/home/netserv/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p357/gems/builder-3.0.0/lib/builder/xmlbase.rb:155:in `call'
/home/netserv/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p357/gems/builder-3.0.0/lib/builder/xmlbase.rb:155:in `_nested_structures'
/home/netserv/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p357/gems/builder-3.0.0/lib/builder/xmlbase.rb:63:in `method_missing'
/home/netserv/RubymineProjects/crawler/lib/jobs/generate_xml.rb:21:in `perform'
/home/netserv/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p357/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/relation/batches.rb:72:in `find_in_batches'
/home/netserv/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p357/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/querying.rb:8:in `__send__'
/home/netserv/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p357/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/querying.rb:8:in `find_in_batches'
/home/netserv/RubymineProjects/crawler/lib/jobs/generate_xml.rb:20:in `perform'
/home/netserv/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p357/gems/builder-3.0.0/lib/builder/xmlbase.rb:155:in `call'
/home/netserv/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p357/gems/builder-3.0.0/lib/builder/xmlbase.rb:155:in `_nested_structures'
/home/netserv/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p357/gems/builder-3.0.0/lib/builder/xmlbase.rb:63:in `method_missing'
/home/netserv/RubymineProjects/crawler/lib/jobs/generate_xml.rb:19:in `perform'
```

Comment: explain how  is Generatexml not able to map to Result class correctly. what errors are you getting? stack trace?

Comment: that's the entire trace - `Undefined method - NOMethod error with Resque gem`? No line number?

Comment: I am really sorry I have edited the question with the trace output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`find_in_batches` [returns arrays](http://railsapi.com/doc/v2.3.2/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches/ClassMethods.html#M001549). Inside the `Postings` block, you could do this:

```
  Result.find_in_batches do |results|
    results.each do
      xml.Posting do
        xml.JobID result.job_id
        xml.JobURL result.job_url
      end
    end
  end
```

But why even bother with `find_in_batches`?

Comment: added this to your second line worked like a charm                                                      results.each do |result|
Thanks

Comment: Also can you please tell  how to save the xml as file ?

Answer (score 0):

`find_in_batches` is [returning an Array](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Batches/ClassMethods/find_in_batches).

You have to update or create a specific `Result` and not update an `Array` of `Results`, what ever that meant.